# The name 'userAge' does not exist in this context

Tags: c#

Im creating a simple calculation program as i am learning C#. I do not understand how to make a user input an Integer when you cannot convert a string into an Int. I am using 'Int.Parse' to assign the input as an integer but it the console says that userAge does not exist in this context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PlanetCalculations {

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        // Your Age
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Age:");
            userAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(userAge);

        // Length of years on Jupiter (in Earth years)
            double jupiterYears = 11.86;

        // Age on Jupiter
        // Time to Jupiter
        // New Age on Earth
        // New Age on Jupiter
        // Log calculations to console
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int userAge =` ??

Comment: `var userAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: " when you cannot convert a string into an Int" -- why can't you?  This is a very common thing to do.

Comment: In C#, all variables must be declared before use.  Using the methods recommended, `int userAge = ??` or `var userAge = ??` allows you to define and assign a variable on the same line.

Comment: Variables in C# must be declared.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston it displays an error when i use Convert to an Int

Comment: You can try to convert it. Check Int32.TryParse function

Comment: @KianL *Show us* how you are trying to do that.  You are doing it wrong.  You **can** convert a string to an int.  This is not in dispute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
userAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

use

```
int userAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

With `int` in front of userAge, you define the variable. Without `int` the program does not know a variable named userAge.

Also, consider using [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) instead of int.Parse like this:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
bool isValidInt = int.TryParse(userInput, out int userAge);

if (!isValidInt)
{
    //False user input...
    Console.WriteLine($"Input '{userInput}' is not an integer. Exiting program ...")
    return;
}
```

Comment: Great answer and explanation, it will help other user's that may come across this solution as well.

Comment: I would just like to jump in and correct the answer a little bit. If really a new person in C# comes here, he will think that you only can use int. That is not incorrect and the answer he provided is it. But you can also place var instead of int.

Comment: @Ryukote Just because you can do it does not always mean you should. In this case there's not really a difference, both ways are just fine.

Comment: There is no difference between those. The only difference is that some developer either him or someone else can u derstand it is integer he is working with if you ise int instead of var. But besides that, there is really no difference.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see you have never defined that variable. Place var before it and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, in your case, I would use `TryParse()` instead of `Parse()`.  With `Parse()` if the user enters a value that can not be converted to a string, it will throw an error.  It would look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Age:");
int userAge;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userAge));
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a valid number.");
}
```

`TryParse()` returns `true` if the conversion worked. If it fails, it returns false.  And if the conversion worked, then `userAge` will contain the numeric value that was entered.